# Algorithm Html compression

Tags: html, algorithm, compression

Do someone know best algorithm for compressing html code? 
I don't care about speed, dictionary size and other things like that but just ultimate compression

I know about gzip, but I want something better.

Comment: Are you compressing to pass to something that you have full control of at the other end? e.g. not a web browser where it is limited to formats it knows about.

Comment: @scunliffe not a web browser, I have full control on other end, so I can choose any algorithm

Comment: My guess is that if your html source _only_ contains standard tags and attributes you may be able to beat the general purpose algorithms using something like Huffman with a fixed dictionary of known, common html phrases, but if your html has even moderate amounts of custom text within them you'll have a hard time beating bzip2 and friends. One issue you'll have with a custom dictionary is that _everything_ you'll encounter must be present there, otherwise you'll need escapement logic, and that causes your compressed stream to grow.

Comment: You need to define your requirements better than "ultimate compression." You say that you don't care about compression, but I don't really believe that. Is it okay to take a full day to compress a megabyte of HTML? Are you willing to write a custom compressor, or are you just asking for suggestions of which of the currently available compressors is the best for HTML? Will this be used from the command line, or are you looking for a library of code that you can call from within your program?

Comment: @Jim Mischel Actually I just looking for direction where to dive. If there available such algorithm that's good, otherwise I can implement it using description. So it is not important. One day for compression is extreme case, if page will be compressed in a few seconds (very long time) it will be ok for me. It will be used in my app, but for sure I can run command line utility.

Comment: @Internal Server Error Well, probably I can use compression in a few steps, for example firstly compress tags and then text using different dictionaries, anyway if I know so much information about data to compress it should be easy to beat bzip and other common algorithms. In my case each additional Kb costs significant money for users, that's why it is important.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out bzip2 and lzma. Both may be capable of better compression ratios than gzip and could also be faster.

Are you serving this HTML to a client browser? There may be javascript ports of the decompression algorithms for bzip2 and lzma that you should check out, but be aware these are not supported by the browser natively:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/txt-compression/

Comment: The thing is that I know something about data which I'm going to compress. So I can use this information to achieve better results than "common" algorithms like zip rar and so on. For example I can just create a dictionary of most common terms in my documents and use it for compression. For sure div, a and other tags will be on top. So I think it is possible to achieve better results

Comment: zlib allows for using a preset dictionary. that sounds more like what you're looking for.